# Deleting first four characters from all Post Titles

Tags: posts, title, customization

I have a wordpress autoblog.. I need to delete first four characters from each single post title automatically.. How can I achieve it?

Comment: [You are expected to have researched the problem and made an attempt at solving it before posting a question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: many thanks for the heads up but am not that proficient with wordpress...

Answer (score 4):

You can use 'the_title' filter ([Codex link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title%29))

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'lose_four_chars');

function lose_four_chars($title) {
    if ( is_single()) {
        return substr($title, 4);
    } else {
        return $title;
    }
}
```

Comment: many thanks for the answer.. where do i paste it??

Comment: Put it in your theme's functions.php

Answer (score 1):

Check non single titles

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'lose_four_chars');

function lose_four_chars($title) {
if ( is_single()) :
    return substr($title, 4);
    else:
    return $title;
    endif;
}
```